# Migrate from angular 10 to 11 strange error

Tags: angular

I am trying to update my project with 11 version of angular, only problem I have that i got some error on compile, I am using css from node_modules to inject in my solution, like this in
**angular.json**

```
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss",
          {
            "inject": false,
            "input": "./node_modules/some-library/lib/styles/themes/dark/main.scss",
            "bundleName": "assets/dark"
          },
          {
            "inject": false,
            "input": "./node_modules/some-library/lib/lib/styles/themes/default/main.scss",
            "bundleName": "assets/default"
          }
        ]
```

But when I try to compile i got error like this

**Schema validation failed with the following errors:
Data path ".styles[1].bundleName" should match pattern "^[\w-.]*$".
Data path ".styles[1]" should be string.
Data path ".styles[1]" should match exactly one schema in oneOf.**

I think problem is with "inject": false, but I dont know where I am making mistake, thanks in advance

Comment: Problem is with the version of @angular-devkit/core can you please post your @angular-devkit/core version?

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. have you been able to fix this issue?

Comment: wrong `"bundleName": "assets/dark"` - right: `"bundleName": "dark"` or `"bundleName": "assets_dark"`, remove the **/** sign and be careful of allowed signs in the name for bundleName

Answer (score 4):

The **bundleName** property may not includes **"/"** anymore...
To check if your bundle name is acceptable just run `/^[\w\-.]*$/.test("assets-dark")`, say from the browser console.

Comment: A little more precise. Because I had the same mistake and didn't see it right away. wrong: `"bundleName": "assets/dark"` - right: `"bundleName": "dark"` or `"bundleName": "assets_dark"`. Be careful of allowed signs in the name for bundleName